# How to install magento in subfolder in localhost

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I am trying to install magento from webserver to my localhost. In my localhost magento should stay in a folder as in xampp

```
htdocs/xxx/web/....
```

I have copied the database fine. I have copied all the files,, chaged the local.xml file for database etc..

Now when loaded ,I notice that the js/images/cs files in the source code are refercing from root rather than the folder web.. as in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:9000/prototype/windows/themes/default.css">
```

whish is definitely wrong.. All links in the source are wrong :( Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only see 2 ways

1 - you configure your xampp with wamp or subdomain, and the store will be accessed have to change in system / configuration / web url

2 - creates a folder with the name of the subdomain within the magento folder, copy the index.php and paste it in and then change the calls index.php, and the store will be accessed have to change in system / configuration / web url